# GUI not proper after duplicated xib for ipad?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, xib

I have duplicated iphone xib into iPad xib by duplicating the target, now my most of the xibs are converted properly into iPad size, however some xibs still showing as iphone size only. Apart from that most of the GUI functionalities like Alert View showing, Action sheet are all not as per iPad. What changes do I need to make to work perfectly for iPad.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Edit: GUI ISSUE  I have given two option in that Action sheet YES and NO, only YES showing NO is hiding somewhere..

[image]

thanks

Comment: Are you actually using the iPad version of the nib when the app loads?  If so, please show us the code that does it.

Comment: You want to know how I am loading?

Comment: Yes.  Show us the code that detects the device and loads the correct nib file.

Comment: I have created sample application to test that .. Please check the edit. Xib also I am maintaing the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is not with conversion, Its with the usage of Action sheet in ipad. Check how to use Action sheet in ipad,

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html

it may fix your problem

Answer (score 1):

You aren't loading the correct NIB when the app starts.  This is the code provided by the Xcode "Single View" App Template, which detects the device and loads the appropriate NIB file:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    } else {
        self.viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    }
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Please check the edit for GUI issue, I have given two option in that Action sheet YES and NO, only YES showing NO is hiding somewhere..